# Many-to-many from relational design to dimensional design

Tags: etl, data-warehouse, star-schema, sql-data-warehouse, star-schema-datawarehouse

This is my database design:

[image: relational design]

I make a data warehouse a with 2 fact table  design as you show :

[image: dimensional design]

I want to add Order dimension but the problem is that there is bridge table between product table and order table by the way order table contain 830 rows and Order details table contain 2155 rows.

How can I create order dimension?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing with creating the Order Dim? Where is this bridge table - in your transactional model or your warehouse model (as I can't see it in either) - and why is this affecting your ability to create a dimension table?

Comment: And why is DimDate a DirectQuery table from another databsae?!?  Switch it to Import.